# Use of both destuctor and Finalize in C++/CLI class

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, c++-cli

I have a `ref class` in `C++/CLI`, which has, amongst its members, a pointer to an `unmanaged` class in C++. An object of this class, when instantiated, associates the pointer to the unmanaged object, like so :

```
m_managed_class (m_another_managed_class^ src) : m_another_managed_class(src) { m_managed_class = new m_Unmanaged_class(*(src->GetInner())); }; // constuctor
```

Notice - this class implements `IDisposable` class. It has a `desctuctor`, which should free up the memory held within the object.

However, I seem to find that this is perhaps a cause of leaking memory, and that somehow the memory associated with the `unmanaged` object is not getting freed up.

If I refer to this class, using an object in `C#`, using a Dispose() on the object does nothing. I wonder, when the object goes out of scope, the destructor should be called and it ought to free up the memory held inside. Should I write an explicit `Finalize` method, and have the memory freed up there?

Comment: See my example of doing this correctly: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1695/2150

Comment: A C# program's Dispose() call invokes your destructor.  So you are a million miles away from diagnosing a memory leak.  Native C++ code rarely needs much help to leak, use umhd.exe or crtdbg.h to find it.  Preferably in a unit test.  You *must* implement a finalizer, disposal is optional.

Comment: Forgive me, for curiosity, why is a` Finalizer` obligatory? If I free up the resources in a desctuctor, which is the `Dispose()` call in `C#`, then, if I had been using the object within a `using` statement, would the Dispose() not get called at the end of it, and release the memory?

Comment: Calling Dispose is a manual operation that is entirely up to the user of your class. Although C# ("using") and C++/CLI (stack semantics) offer syntactic sugar to help, it is all too common for a user to forget to dispose an object. The finalizer on the other hand is guaranteed to run at some point during the GC process (well, almost: see http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/). So the only way to be (reasonably) sure that unmanaged resources will get freed is to implement a finalizer: Dispose is a manual mechanism to do it in a more deterministic fashion.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation.